# IOS Populate a Twitter post

Tags: swift3, xcode7

I'm looking for a little help on how to populate text into a twitter post, using the button below I can get a label to show "00:35' Goal for"

When the button is clicked I would like to open twitter which I can work out, and populate it ready for tweeting.

```
@IBAction func goalClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

        tempTimelineLbl.text = "\(stopWatchString)'  \("Goal for")"
}
```

I will use the code below to open twitter

```
 let twUrl: URL = URL(string: "twitter://user?screen_name=\(club.twitter)")!
            let twUrlWeb: URL = URL(string: "https://twitter.com/\(club.twitter)")!

            if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(twUrl)) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(twUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: {
                    (Sucess) in
                })
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.open(twUrlWeb, options: [:], completionHandler: {
                    (Sucess) in
                })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Followed this

https://developer.apple.com/reference/social/slcomposeviewcontroller

```
@IBAction func goalClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let stopWatchString = stopWatch.elapsedTimeSinceStart()
        stopwatchLabel.text = stopWatchString

        let vc = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
        vc?.setInitialText("Some Test String")
        vc?.add(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "goal"))
        present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```